# Allow permanent access to IIS express

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, remote-access

To access my IIS Express project remotely, I changed the application config file in `PROJECT_FOLDER\.vs\config\applicationhost.config` and changed the line

`<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50584:localhost" />`

to

`<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50584:*" />`

and it works perfectly, but everytime I reopen the project in Visual Studio, it adds a new `site` block with the binding information binded to localhost. How do I change this so that I don't have to change this line everytime ?

Comment: Try changing the same lines in the `applicationhost.config` file in the IISExpress directory.

Comment: I can't, there is no such line in this file

Comment: There is no `applicationhost.config` file under `C:\Users\username\Documents\IISExpress\config`?

Comment: Yes there is, but there is no line with binding information, not for the port I'm looking for at least

Comment: Odd, when I look in my file I can see the bindings for all my IIS sites